# Docker: Error: Could not find or load main class org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher

Tags: java, spring, docker

I'm trying to containerize my service.

My Docker File:

```
FROM openjdk:19 as builder
WORKDIR application
ARG JAR_FILE=target/payment-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} application.jar
RUN java -Djarmode=layertools -jar application.jar extract

FROM openjdk:19
WORKDIR application
COPY --from=builder application/dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/spring-boot-loader ./
COPY --from=builder application/snapshot-dependencies/ ./
COPY --from=builder application/application/ ./
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

Console commands:

```
mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage
docker build -t payment-service .
docker run --network test_net --name payment-service -d payment-service
```

Then I see this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

My target folder:

[image: target]

If my Dockerfile looks like that, all is works:

```
FROM openjdk:19

COPY target/payment-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar payment-service.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/payment-service.jar"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found:

Just change

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

To:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher"]
```